# Ansible- How to include /import playbook based on when condition result

Tags: ansible

I have folder in which i have many sub folder and those sub folder will have yaml file, by using the below code , I have got all yaml file and register those file,

```
  tasks:
- name: Find .yml files
  find:
    paths: /temp/
    patterns: '*.yml,*.yaml'
    recurse: yes
  register: yaml_path_files
```

One of the yaml file content is below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: special-config
  namespace: default
data:
  special.how: very
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-config
  namespace: default
data:
  log_level: INFO
  
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-config
  namespace: default
data:
  log_level: INFO
```

i want to check if the yaml contains kind is ConfigMap and that yaml file needs to be passed to role/another playbook as parmeter,i tried with below code, it is not working,

```
    - debug:
    var: item.path
  when: lookup('file',item.path ) | from_yaml_all | list | selectattr('kind', '==', 'ConfigMap') | list | length > 0
  with_items: "{{ yaml_path_files.files }}"
```

i am facing the below error,

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'lookup('file',item.path ) | from_yaml | list | selectattr('kind', '==', 'ConfigMap') | list | length > 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (lookup('file',{{ filename }} ) | from_yaml | list | selectattr('kind', '==', 'ConfigMap') | list | length > 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'kind'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/cygdrive/c/senthil/Ansible/Ansibleusecase4/EKSartifactvalidationV2.yml': line 14, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      # with_items: "{{ yaml_path_files.files }}"\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

kindly help me  to achive it in ansible

Answer (score 1):

*Preliminary note: Your question is missing a complete playbook to be 100% sure of the problem. Edit your question with more info, possibly with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if this is not your exact issue.*

Your [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) tasks looks for files on your remote target. The [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html), as all other lookups (see notes in the [lookup plugins documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)), reads files locally on your ansible controller. In other words, you're looking for a file which does not exists.

You have to [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html) or [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) the files from the remote target to get their content.

Here is a quickly written untested sample to put you on track. Please note on the last task that `item.item.path` is not a typo. `item.item` references the preceding item loop  when registering the new var `yaml_files_content` (i.e. each  `yaml_path_files.files[*]` from the preceding task, debug the full `item` to see for yourself)

```yaml
- hosts: all
  
  tasks:
    - name: Find .yml files
      find:
        paths: /temp/
        patterns: '*.yml,*.yaml'
        recurse: yes
      register: yaml_path_files

    - name: Slurp file contents from remote
      slurp:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ yaml_path_files.files }}"
      register: yaml_files_contents
   
    - name: Show path for files containing ConfigMaps
      debug:
        var: item.item.path
      loop: "{{ yaml_files_contents.results }}"
      when: item.content | b64decode | from_yaml_all | list | selectattr('kind', '==', 'ConfigMap') | list | length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , By adding the below code, it works fine for me,
when: lookup('file',item.path).splitlines() | map('lower') | select('match','^kind:\s+configmap$') | list | length > 0